# Como alinear horizontalmente buttons con Bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una serie de 4 `buttons` en mi vista de ASP.NET MVC. Me quedan los 4 en sentido vertical, que formas hay para poder dejarlos los 4 horizontalmente?.

He probado jugando con las `class` `col-xs-6` en todos pero no me ha funcionado.

Dejo mi código:

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="EnviarCheck()" id="enviarChk">Confirmar lectura</button>
                    <p id="pMensaje"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="div_imprimir" class="col-xs-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Imprimir('div_oculto_imprimir')" id="ImprimirImg">Imprimir</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ReporteToExcel", "Mi" )" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary botonExcel" id="btn_pdf"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Exportar Excel</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ExportarPDF", "Mi" )"  class="btn btn-primary botonPDF" id="btn_pdf_comparador_ci"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Exportar PDF</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta fue la ultima modificación que hice y me quedo asi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola amigo el problema es que usas xs-6 y eso hace que se parta en dos, el tamaño tenlo en cuenta siempre sera máximo de 12 es decir como pones de a 6 entonces solo puedes tener como máximo dos botones, si quisieras que estén los 4 ahí

entonces divide 12/4=3 entonces cada uno debe de ser de 3.

Otro punto xs,md etc son para los tamaños.

Aquí te muestro como quedaría saludos.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="EnviarCheck()" id="enviarChk">Confirmar lectura</button>
                    <p id="pMensaje"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="div_imprimir" class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Imprimir('div_oculto_imprimir')" id="ImprimirImg">Imprimir</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ReporteToExcel", "Mi" )" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary botonExcel" id="btn_pdf"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Exportar Excel</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ExportarPDF", "Mi" )"  class="btn btn-primary botonPDF" id="btn_pdf_comparador_ci"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Exportar PDF</a>
                </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas graciasss he podido resolver el problema

Comment: De nada....Saludos

Answer (score 5):

Ten en cuenta que la **alineación horizontal** en Bootstrap consta de un espacio total de **12 columnas**, esto quiere decir que te estás **excediendo** en el doble de la longitud de la pantalla.

Por otra parte, estás reduciendo al tamaño mínimo las longitudes (**-xs-** *formato para dispositivos móviles*). Te aconsejo que lo hagas en un tamaño medio (**-md-** *tablets y monitores pequeños*)`. Eso si, cuando visualices en dispositivos móviles (*responsive*), los botones te aparecerán apilados en disposición vertical (como debería ser).

El código para que se visualice de manera correcta es el siguiente:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="EnviarCheck()" id="enviarChk">Confirmar lectura</button>
                <p id="pMensaje"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="div_imprimir" class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Imprimir('div_oculto_imprimir')" id="ImprimirImg">Imprimir</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ReporteToExcel", "Mi" )" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary botonExcel" id="btn_pdf"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Exportar Excel</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ExportarPDF", "Mi" )"  class="btn btn-primary botonPDF" id="btn_pdf_comparador_ci"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Exportar PDF</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que el número de columnas en Bootstrap debe sumar 12.

Por otro lado, en Bootstrap 4, las columnas se pueden dejar automáticas (dejando solo `col` en la clase css.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="EnviarCheck()" id="enviarChk">Confirmar lectura</button>
                        <p id="pMensaje"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div_imprimir" class="col">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Imprimir('div_oculto_imprimir')" id="ImprimirImg">Imprimir</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("ReporteToExcel", "Mi" )" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary botonExcel" id="btn_pdf"><i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Exportar Excel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("ExportarPDF", "Mi" )"  class="btn btn-primary botonPDF" id="btn_pdf_comparador_ci"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i>Exportar PDF</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```